# Generate doc use docx4j, it gose different on windows and linux server

Tags: java, linux, windows, docx4j

when I use docx4j to generate doc from HTML and output through java servlet, it works well on Windows system, I can download and open the doc file normally.

When I put the project on Linux server, I can also download the doc file, but when openging file, it alert that the file is broken. I must click the confirm and restore the file.then open it normally.
my core code is like this.

how can i get the same result as windows?

code in jsp:

```
 String vhtml = DownHtml2DocUtil.replaceSvgData2Base64(request);
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");//设置为字节流
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = response.getOutputStream();
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".doc");
        DownHtml2DocUtil.genDocFromHtml(vhtml, output);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    response.flushBuffer();
    out.clear();
    out = pageContext.pushBody();
```

code in java like this:

```
public static void genDocFromHtml(String html, OutputStream out)
   throws EMPException {
  try {
   WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage;
   wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
   XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(
     wordMLPackage);
   wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent()
     .addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert(html, "utf-8"));
//   wordMLPackage.save(out);  -- i tried both method
   new Save(wordMLPackage).save(out);
  } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
   throw new EMPException(e);
  } catch (Docx4JException e) {
   throw new EMPException(e);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

any suggestion will be appreciate , thanks  anyway;

Comment: You need to unzip the docx files and compare their contents to see what is different.

Comment: thankyou very much!how to do that,is there any method or tool i can use.

Comment: @JasonPlutext thank you my friend ,i renamed the doc file to .zip file,and unzip them into a folder and then compared the two folders. then i found some differences.now i am going forward.

Comment: Microsoft's Open XML SDK contains a useful tool for comparing 2 docx files.